# How to reload html src of an image in django

Tags: python, html, django

My Django app import an image from the media_url and then it goes to the next page and shows the image and goes back to first page then a new image imported and the old image is removed.
The problem is that at the first loop everything is good, in the second loop, it appears that html shows the old image not the new one. how can I apply a reloading in html. here is part of the code:

**settings.py:**

```
 MEDIA_ROOT = 'media//' # I test the MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
 MEDIA_URL = 'media//'
```

**views.py:**

```
 def scraping(request):
     ....
     template_name = "scraping.html"
     response2 = {'media_root': Config.MEDIA_ROOT, 'media_url': Config.MEDIA_URL}
     return render(request, template_name, response2)
```

**scraping.html**

```
  <img src='{{media_url}}/pic.jpg//'> # I also tried {{media_url}}pic.jpg 
                                                     {{media_url}}/pic.jpg/
                                                     {{media_url}}//pic.jpg//
```

Comment: you can use `location.reload();` to reload an HTML page using Javascript

Comment: It made the scraping.html to reload and reload again. I wrote it like this:

Comment: <script>location.reload();</script>
        <img src="{{media_url}}IMG/pic.jpg/"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't find any answer for my question, but I solved my problem bypassing this issue.
In the previous version, I tried to import an image , rename it into pic.jpg and call it on the html file. this caused the web to show me all the pre-removed pic.jpg.
Now, I rename all the imported image to a specific name (by date.now()) and this helped html not to get confused by the similar name of the files.
But still I don't know why the html file wouldn't refresh the image even if the name of the source files are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below :

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media')
```

Comment: Thanks. Changing to your code made no difference. it still needs a refreshing in src dir in html, I think!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't got any answer yet, but I realize something. first I changed the media directory to static.
here it is:

**scraping.html**

```
<img src='{{static_url}}/' \>
<img src='{{static_url}}//' \>
<img src='{{static_url}}///' \>
```

each time I have to add a "/" in src to reload my image as it is right now.
if I delete one "/" after refreshing it goes to previous image.
I played a lot in settings and views and html by replacing "/" and "\" but I don't have any clue why its happening